# Image pop up when certain list item is selected - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, list

I am trying to get an image to pop up for each item in a drop down list to act as a visual aid and for data accuracy

The list code is:

```
<P style=font-size:0></P>Accident Code: <BR>
<form name="accident" action="">
    <select id='List6' name='List6'>
    <option selected>Make a selection</option>
</select>
&nbsp;
<select id='List7' name='List7' onchange="getValue3(this.value, this.form['List6'].value, 
    this.form['List6'].value)">
    <option selected ></option>
</select></P>
</form>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry I am not getting an error, I am more asking how to get different images to pop up on certain list selections

Answer (score 0):

You have set the `style` attribute on your `p` tag in a wrong manner and put the `</p>` in a wrong place. I am not sure where to place `</p>` but you can change accordingly
Edited code:

```
<p style="font-size:0"></p>Accident Code: <BR>
<form name="accident" action="">
    <select id='List6' name='List6'>
       <option selected>Make a selection</option>
    </select>
&nbsp;
<select id='List7' name='List7' onchange="getValue3(this.value, this.form['List6'].value, 
    this.form['List6'].value)">
    <option selected ></option>
</select>
</form>
```

And for adding images in your `select` tag add these to your CSS:

```
#List6 option[value=value1]{
   background-image:url(img1.png); 
}

#List6 option[value=value2]{
   background-image:url(img2.png); 
}

#List7 option[value=value1]{
   background-image:url(img11.png); 
}

/*And so on.. */
```

And you can also you use [this](http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render). It is exactly what you need

Comment: I may have missed it, can you please be more specific about the link and where it adds images? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the link, it is very interesting, however, I more meant how to get a local image to pop up next to the drop down list, rather than  inside of it because that would be too small for my use

Comment: This is sort of what I am after, I am just having trouble implementing it in my code because of the second drop down list I think

http://jsfiddle.net/treyh/xf2pq/

Comment: I am unsure of the syntax to get the images to show up when I choose different options in my list

Comment: It's perfectly fine. Please tick the answer if I helped.